# javascript on click events

Tags: php, javascript

Is there any way to get pass the variables from one php page to another using javascript and get the the output of it without loading the page?? Note that variables should pass only using javascript. I

Comment: Consider using an AJAX call, though technically that's also 'loading the page', only that the user doesn't realize that.

Comment: But i am not using ajax and i want user does not realize that page loaded, and it should be done using javascript, any idea?

Comment: @user2009243: You might be able to do that with iframes. Although Ajax would be easier. Ajax is done through JavaScript. Read more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started.

Comment: Ajax is part of JavaScript, please explain more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to avoid using PHP you can try 3 methods:

1. Saving data to cookies.
2. Saving data to local storage. (not relyable because of compatibility)
3. Passing variables between windows. (may not match your problem)

## 1. Cookies

This is easyest and most relyable method. But **be aware - user can edit and view data**. You should google yourself some articles about that, tahie this one (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) for starter to understand the topic.

## 2. Local storage

Some browsers may have this utility disabled or not implemented at all. Advantage of this is, that, unlike cookies, this data are not sent with HTTP request headers so you can save some traffic.
Google again. There is nothing I can tell you about theese what google can't.

## 3. Passing variables between windows

This only works for very specific case - when you have two windows and one of them is opened via `window.open()` function. This function returns new window handle.

```
var child_window = window.open(/*params*/);
child_window.document.title = "Hello world!";
```

But still you should consider using AJAX to save variables on server and retrieve them from here.